# create-react-app vs create-mf-app what is the difference

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I would like to create micro frontend in react. But what confuse me why there is create-mf-app and how it is different from create-react-app. Create react app can do micro frontend too.

Comment: pretty sure a single websearch, or even just looking at npm, gets you that answer? One is the popular react app creation tool, the other is some random package with barely any users that explicitly calls out that it's not production ready.

Comment: sorry i am new to react. i search but not many article gives info, so you mean better to use create-react-app? create-mf-app not stable / good?

Answer (score 5):

`npx create-react-app my-app` creates a React app using the [official start project](https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-react-app). It offers a modern build setup with no configuration.

`npx create-mf-app` creates a Module Federation application, API server, or library based on one of multiple different templates. These projects are [not production ready](https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-mf-app). They are designed as lightweight projects that can be used to quickly prototype a new feature or library.

Comment: i see. so create-react-app should be suitable if we plan to use if for live correct (production)?